# Acumatica PXSelector search filter where value is zero

Tags: acumatica

Can the search filter for a PXSelector in Acumatica be set to a zero value?

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DAC.fieldID,
  Where<DAC.fieldQty, Equal<decimal?.Zero>>>))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a BQL Constant

in this case

```
public class DecimalZero : BqlDecimal.Constant<DecimalZero >
{
    public DecimalZero() : Base(0M)
}
```

And then

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DAC.fieldID,
  Where<DAC.fieldQty, Equal<DecimalZero>>>))]
```

Use this same method for other constants, BqlString.Constant<> BqlInt.Constant<> ETC